# Image not loaded in jQuery load() of a HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I am using following code to load a html page inside a div,

```
$("#htmlViewer").load("conversion_test/to_convert_3264/"+getPageName(pageCount)+".htm", function(response, status, xhr) {
                   if (status == "error") {
                     /* var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                     $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText); */
                     jAlert('Unexpected Error : Please try again later', 'Alert');
                     pageCount--;
                   }
                 });
```

In the above code I am getting only the HTML text but I am not getting CSS and the images in that page. To get the CSS I added another Ajax request. Without this the page loaded in ajax call will not have the css styles applied.

```
$.ajax({
            url:"conversion_test/to_convert_3264/style.css",
            success:function(data){
                 $("<style></style>").appendTo("head").html(data);
            }
        })
```

I am not sure this is the right way to go about it. The problem is I am not getting the images during the ajax call. The images come from `conversion_test/to_convert_3264/images` folder.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know If I need to give more details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are not requesting **images**. Your ajax call can only request the *uri/url* you have specified.

Comment: Thank you,  but How to make the images display any suggestions please ?

Comment: is it possible to load the images folder dynamically so that the images will be displayed?

Comment: That is not possible via jQuery - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

Comment: Is the page that makes the Ajax call in the same folder as the called page? Could the problem be that the images are referenced relatively to the target page, which means they are wrong in the page that code is inserted into?

Comment: Thank you @AVD I will look in to it.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: @MiikaL. No the page is on the different folder.  I agree that is the problem. Is there any way to resolve that.  You are right All the images are referred relatively.  Thank you for editing my post and answering me..

Comment: You would need to either change the image references to absolute references (with the full folder path), or then use jQuery to traverse the images and insert the necessary path. Is it possible for you to test to see if that works

Comment: There are lots of files... So I need to try your second option..  Changing the image path..  I will try it and update you.. thank you for the help..

Comment: @MiikaL. I tried your suggestion and now I got the images.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I will post my answer here.  You can state your idea as answer and I can mark it as correct.  Thanks a lot..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will write this as an answer so its a bit more obvious than just the comment thread:

The problem is that the calling page is not located in the same folder as the page being called. The target page references the images with relative paths, and thus when its inserted into the calling page, those references no longer match. In other words, the context of the page has changed.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Use absolute paths for the images so that the context doesn't matter.
2. Use jQuery to fix the paths in the received html (Dilip came up with the code for this himself in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12086783/1025176)).

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed based on the @MiikaL suggestion.  Following is my code to solve the problem.

```
function replaceImageSource() {
       $("img").each( function(){
              $(this).attr({
                 src: 'conversion_test/to_convert_3264/' + $(this).attr('src')
              });
            });
    }
```

Hope this helps some one.  Thanks for all your help.